# The best way to avoid LSP violation

Tags: c#, oop, solid-principles

Let's consider the following example. I have the hierarchy of the classes like this:

```
abstract class Base
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}

class Foo : Base
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo. DoSomething...");
    }
}

class Bar : Base
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar. DoSomething...");

        if (ShouldDoSomethingElse)
        {
            DoSomethingElse();
        }
    }

    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar. DoSomething else...");
    }

    public bool ShouldDoSomethingElse { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the client something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        var bar = new Bar();
        var items = new List<Base> {foo, bar};

        HandleItems(items);
    }

    static void HandleItems(IEnumerable<Base> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item is Bar)
            {
                //Code smell! LSP violation.
                var bar = item as Bar;
                bar.ShouldDoSomethingElse = true;
            }
            item.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that we can have several clients some of which may need ShouldDoSomethingElse = 'true' others 'false'.

Definitely, handling the items differently in HandleItems() is a sign of bad design and Liskov Substitution Principle violation.

What approach or pattern would you advise to get rid of this code smell?

I am sorry if similar questions have already been asked.

Answer (score 6):

Your code does not violate the Liskov Substitution Principle. The principle merely states that all sub types must behave in a compatible way without breaking the consumer when a different implementation is injected. In your example. the code will not break when you supply different types.

Still however, the downcast to `Bar` is a code smell, because `HandleItems` violates the Dependency Inversion Principle, because `HandleItems` now depends on concrete types instead of abstractions. Besides, this code could lead to an Open/Closed Principle violation later on, because you might need to change the `HandleItems` method each time a new `Base` sub type is added. Once you need to change `HandleItems` it means it is not closed for modification.

Your example however is abstract, which makes it hard to give some precise feedback, but in general I would say that you should move the responsibility of setting the `ShouldDoSomethingElse` to the caller, such as:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Bar { ShouldDoSomethingElse = true };
var items = new List<Base> { foo, bar };

HandleItems(items);
```

This prevents the `HandleItems` from having to know anything about the derived types (which allows derived types to be deployed separately) and prevents `HandleItems` from ever changing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want different bahavior depending on the client, let the client pass an argument to DoSomething that tells the method what to do. Or create two different methods and leave it up to the client which one to call.

I am not sure I understand the problem. You use polymorphism and then render it pointless by determining the type and acting based on that knowledge. DoSomething should already do something class specific, the point of polymorphism is to leave the client unaware of the different implementations and still get the appropriate behavior.